# Digital potentiometer DS3502 question

Tags: digital, potentiometer

I am using adafruit DS3502 breakout board for arduino. When I follow procedure written in
https://learn.adafruit.com/ds3502-i2c-potentiometer/arduino

My serial display shows correct voltage values.

My question is: When I remove RL,RH, RW pins from arduino and measure resistance between RW and RL or RW and RH with a multimeter, it doesnt show correct value in ohms. It shows between 300 to 400 K Ohms. Anyone knows is this known behaviour or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: If you ground the (-) lead of the meter and probe the RW pin while programmatically  changing the steps, do you get reasonable values?  See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590633/is-there-a-better-way-to-determine-the-resistance-of-a-digital-potentiometer-tha

Comment: NO...doesnt read values at all like this.